How can I fix an issue where I see the docker containers using the cli tool but the Desktop is empty (Ubuntu/Gnome 24)?
I am trying to get docker desktop working with my Gnome Ubuntu installation. I can get Docker desktop to start (using this hack sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0), but I don't see the containers.

Do I need to set some permissions or something to get the containers to show up in the same way?

Sounds like you have a docker engine running on the Ubuntu host and have been interacting with it (while Docker Desktop runs its docker host in a VM). There's probably a way (env var maybe?) to make the CLI client programs on the Ubuntu host talk to the docker host in the VM as well.

Any good way to start confirming that is the case?

Maybe this would give you some insight on where to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173489/docker-socket-is-not-found-while-using-intellij-idea-and-docker-desktop-on-macos
